# Proper way to use lambdas in Razor MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, lambda

I'm having some trouble understanding how to manipulate model data in the cshtml page. Most of my issue may be as a result of not fully understanding how/why lambdas are used.

one example of something I wanted to do but was unable to is below:

(This code doesn't work)

```
@model Combined.Models.Task

<div>
@string x = model => model.fileString

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.files, new { @class = "form-control", type = "file", multiple = "true", placeholder = x})
</div>
```

`model.files` is a datatype that can accept file input, but will be empty in this context.

`model.fileString` is a string representation of the files that I would like to load into that text box

---

edit

To simplify:

I want to use the data stored in model.fileString, but I cant seem to figure out how to access it. When I try to use it in the form model => model.fileString I get errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to do :)
As for the first part :
If you want to output your files as a string you can do it in a few ways, with or without lambda.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.fileString)
<input type="text" value="@Model.fileString"/>
<p>@Model.fileString</p>
```

As far as the file submiting goes you need an input type file and a form with multipart encoding for that, can't use a textbox(which is for text only)

```
<form method="POST" action="@Url.Action("SubmitFiles",)" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="filePropertyName" />
<input type="submit" value="submitMyForm"/>
```

I think you are trying to force lambda due to the automatic name generation of the For methods(TextAreaFor,HiddenFor,...)
But you can do the naming just as easily yourself. My File input for example has the name filePropertyName. Mvc model binder will match this name with a property of your viewmodel or a parameter of your post method.

Comment: I guess to try and put it more simply, I want to use the data stored in `model.fileString`, but I cant seem to figure out how to access it. When I try to use it in the form `model => model.fileString` I get errors.  Edit: okay I think I understand now. Thanks